# SQLite Database not connected in Django Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

So i was trying to deploy my project to Heroku and i followed this steps : https://www.codementor.io/@jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4
. The build was successfull and i was able to run the server : https://pcbuildingparts.herokuapp.com/
but the database doesn't seem to connect beacause the items from database doesn't show at all and i tried to login in my admin site with my superuser account before deploying, but it doesn't let me in.
This is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for dss_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5u53+p4k-_=70wwg-igg7_5r9!5vh-c6@@hcl&**(e6fod8d(a'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['pcbuildingparts.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
    'blog',
    'accounts',
    'sim',
    'dss',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dss_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dss_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'id'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
PROJECT_ROOT   =   os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

import dj_database_url
prod_db  =  dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason as to why you want to use SQLite on Heroku? A great option would be to use the [postgress addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) and use SQLite for local development and testing.

See how to connect to postgres in Django: [postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-with-django)
You can also use the [django-heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) package to easily configure your django app.

Comment: well there's no reason actually, because the default db for django as far as i know is sqlite. and i have deployed other project before with sqlite and there's no problem

Comment: Heroku hosts another instance of the database on its server, which is why it is empty. Try running "heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser" to create a superuser in the production database and try to log in.

Comment: i did what you said, and it seems that the tables is still there, but all the records are empty, i don't get it, i thought when i run ```heroku run python manage.py migrate``` after i push the project it would migrate them. is there another way to migrate the database from local ?

Comment: it turns out i forgot that  i already choose postgresql long time ago before i even push my project when i was trying to deploy with the same app name in heroku. that explain the answer for my first comment. and i guess i just have to changed to postgresql like you said because it's more suitable.

Comment: The migrate command synchronises the database with your models and previous migrations. It doesn't make any items "appear" anywhere. Your database on Heroku does not have access to the records stored in your local db.sqlite3 file, which is why you don't see them there. Basically you are dealing with two different databases, one that you use for development locally, and another one that you have connected to whatever server is hosting your site (in this case Heroku).